# git filter-branch: options not supported in --stdin mode

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I'm trying to rename some commit messages using `git filter-branch --msg-filter` in windows cmd like this:

```
git filter-branch --msg-filter "python my_editing_script.py" -- --first-parent --no-merges 37827a6c7a65f8e878e..my_branch_name
```

The `my_editing_script.py` reads old messages from `stdin` and outputs new ones to `stdout`.

But I get

```
fatal: options not supported in --stdin mode
Could not get the commits
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @petrpulc  I want to ignore commits that were merged from other branches, as well as merge commits themselves. This is achieved by passing arguments `--first-parent --no-merges` to `rev-list`.

Comment: First, try if `git rev-list --first-parent --no-merges 37827a6c7a65f8e878e..my_branch_name` works. If it does, store the output of it and pass to filter-branch

Comment: It works, but how do I pass them to `filter-branch`?

Comment: Seems that `--no-merges` causes all the troubles. My understanding is that you cannot break history anywhere during filtering, see last part of https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_examples

Comment: Maybe try to handle the merge commits on your own in the `my_editing_script.py`